# Calling a function gives Reference error as function undefined

Tags: javascript

I have 2 JS files - `first.js` and `second.js`
I have defined a function `call()` directly in `second.js`, without enclosing it under anything.

```
#second.js

function call(){
        console.log('output');
}
```

Now, when I call it from first.js it gives reference error as function `call()` is undefined.

```
#first.js

 function test(){
  call();
 }
```

I am calling both these separate js files in the following order in my main.html

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="second.js"> </script>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="first.js"> </script>
```

Since second is included prior to first, function `call()` is already there, also not wrapped inside any other function, why am I getting reference error?

**EDIT:** - As suggested, I checked `second.js` that has an onclick function which was causing problem - `element.onclick = function(){ $.get('{{url_for('python_function')}}'); }`. I changed it to `element.onclick = function(){ $.get('{{url_for(python_function)}}'); }`and everything is fine now.

Comment: Are you sure the `second` is being loaded correctly? No syntax errors or anything? Need a [MCVE]

Comment: No sir, I can see it under console as the sole error, nothing else.

Comment: Can't reproduce it on my end, there must be some code or context missing

Comment: Is it misspelling or you literally include those files like that in the `main.JS` file?

Comment: What happens if you type `call();` in the console? Does it run?

Comment: Do you mean your ```main.html``` file?

Comment: Yes, it's main.html file.

Comment: Try this instead  `setTimeout(()=>{test()}, 3000);`

Comment: try to add a console.log('script 1 loaded') and another for script 2 in each file outside any function, make sure both are loaded this way.

Comment: @CertainPerformance There is onclick function in second.js which was causing problem - ` element.onclick = function(){
                                 $.get('{{url_for('python_function')}}');
                         
  
                      }`. After removing it everything works fine in the https server. However, I need this function and things runs fine(without https) on my localhost .

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code.  First, you have to `import` the code from `second.js` into `first.js`.  That would look something like this:

```
#first.js

import <name variable whatever you want> from '<path to second.js>';

 function test(){
  <name of the variable you made in the first line>();
 }

test();
```

Next you need to `export` the function that is in `second.js`, so you would do this:

```
#second.js

export default function call(){
    console.log('output');
}
```

And finally in your HTML you want to specify the type of `first.js` as a `module` instead of `text/javascript` like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="second.js"> </script>

<script type = "module" src="first.js"> </script>
```

**EDIT**

As @connexo pointed out you do not need to include `second.js` in the HTML since you are importing the function directly in `first.js`. So you can do this in your HTML instead:

```
<script type = "module" src="first.js"> </script>
```

Hope this helps!  Let me know if it works for you

Comment: No need to include `second.js` if you're working with modules.

Comment: @connexo you are correct!  I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Thanks for all your help Sir, much appreciated! I have made an edit, please see if you have time.